# How to access the Principal object returned by a LoginCommand?

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds, lcds

How can I access the Principal object in a Flex client that was returned by the `doAuthenticate()` method in the LoginCommand?

Adobe's [LCDS Custom Authentication](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/LiveCycleDataServicesES/3.1/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811f00f7045b-7f36Update.html) page isn't much help in this matter, as this is the only example they show for a successful login:

```
// Handle successful login. 
private function LoginResultEvent(event:ResultEvent, token:Object=null):void  { 
    switch(event.result) { 
        case "success": 
            authenticatedCB.selected = true; 
            break; 
            default: 
    } 
}
```

I can return a strongly typed object as the Principal from the `doAuthenticate()` method, but how do I access it in the client's result handler?

**Update**: I've read the LCDS documentation twice now and there is no mention of accessing the Principal in the client. The only data I can retrieve from a result is the string 'success'. Anyone know if this is this the only result available from a custom authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I use a 2nd call after a successful login, which returns the principle.

Eg.,

```
public User getCurrentUser()
```

Takes no params (username,password), as they're already available in the security context.

Comment: I've been using a 2nd call as well. After reviewing the AsyncToken and ChannelSet classes in the AS Doc, I'm almost convinced it's not possible from the first call. I'm still waiting for someone to tell me otherwise. My second call requires me to pass at least the username. How do you do it with security context?